# Return List<Type> using WHERE clause in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I want to retrieve only the records (persisted using Ebean) where virtualfile equals my *virtualfile_id*

On route http://localhost:9000/transactionRecords I have a couple of records:

```
[{"id":1,"virtualfile":"1","record_type":"D","transaction_type":"MA","card_number":"0000122000200123456","expiry_date":"0000"},
{"id":2,"virtualfile":"1","record_type":"D","transaction_type":"MA","card_number":"0000122000200123456","expiry_date":"0000"},
{"id":3,"virtualfile":"1","record_type":"D","transaction_type":"MA","card_number":"0000122000200123456","expiry_date":"0000"},
{"id":4,"virtualfile":"1","record_type":"D","transaction_type":"MA","card_number":"0000122000200123456","expiry_date":"0000"},
{"id":5,"virtualfile":"1","record_type":"D","transaction_type":"MA","card_number":"0000122000200123456","expiry_date":"0000"}]
```

My route to **GET** them:

```
GET     /generator/:id             controllers.Application.generateFile(id: String)
```

My controller method to fetch them:

```
public Result generateFile(String virtualfile_id) {
    List<TransactionRecord> transactionRecords = TransactionRecord.find.where()
            .ilike("virtualfile", "1") //set to "1" for testing
            .orderBy("id asc")
            .findPagedList(1, 25)
            .getList();
    return ok(toJson(transactionRecords));
}
```

*method to fetch the list as suggested by  [https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean#Using-Model-superclass)

And my TransactionRecord.class

```
@Entity
public class TransactionRecord extends Model {

  @Id
  Long id;
  String virtualfile;
  String record_type;
  String transaction_type;
  String card_number;
  String expiry_date;

  public static Finder<Long,TransactionRecord> find = new Finder<>(Long.class,TransactionRecord.class);

  public TransactionRecord(String virtualfile, String transaction_type, String card_number, String expiry_date) {
      this.virtualfile = virtualfile;
      this.record_type = "D";
      this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
      this.card_number = card_number;
      this.expiry_date = expiry_date;
  }

  getters & setters

}
```

But my output on route http://localhost:9000/generator/1 is empty :( :

[image]

**EDIT:**

If I only change `.iLike` to `.eq` nothing happens.

Result of changing `.ilike` to `.eq` and remove `.findPagedList`:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `ilike` to `eq` and/or remove `findPagedList`?

Comment: @SteveChaloner I updated my question with the result.

Comment: Change `getList` to `findList`

Comment: It works @SteveChaloner, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @SteveChaloner please change your comment to an answer so it can be accepted and this question resolved.

Comment: @Zoltán just did that for Steve

Comment: @SteveChaloner you can copy my post and post it by yourself. Then I will delete my answer

Comment: @SteveChaloner what a nice happy end :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have five records, but in your call to `getPagedList`, you're skipping over the first 25 records.  Consequently, you're skipping all your records.

From the [Ebean documentation](https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/Query.html#findPagedList-int-int-)

> Parameters: 
>   pageIndex - The **zero based** index of the page.
>   pageSize - The number of beans to return per page.

So, initially you need to change the parameter of findPagedList `1` to a `0`.

```
public Result generateFile(String virtualfile_id) {
    List<TransactionRecord> transactionRecords = TransactionRecord.find.where()
        .ilike("virtualfile", "1") //set to "1" for testing
        .orderBy("id asc")
        .findPagedList(0, 25)
        .getList();
    return ok(toJson(transactionRecords));
}
```

To correctly support paging as guided by the client (or, at least, coming from the controller layer) you'll need to change the signature of

```
public Result generateFile(String virtualfile_id)
```

to

```
public Result generateFile(String virtualfile_id, int page)
```

and use that `page` parameter as the argument to `findPagedList`.

```
public Result generateFile(String virtualfile_id,
                           int page) {
    List<TransactionRecord> transactionRecords = TransactionRecord.find.where()
        .ilike("virtualfile", "1") //set to "1" for testing
        .order().asc("id")
        .findPagedList(page, 25)
        .getList();
    return ok(toJson(transactionRecords));
}
```